# Mercurial filemap exclude include... does it not do what docs say?

Tags: mercurial, filemap

Converting from subversion, I take the opportunity to clean up the repo, and split it in three mostly independent projects.  But... I have a filemap that says

```
exclude bot
include bot/aobiosbot.py
```

Which should include everything, except the "bot" subdirectory, but still include the "aobiosbot.py" file in that directory.  The trouble is, the converted repo is empty (I test with an "hg clone").  If I add an "include ." as line 1, I get everything but the "bot" dir... including "bot/aobiosbot.py".  But I told it to *include* that file.

(Really, the docs for filemap are bad. Exclude/include options have to be specified *exactly*.  I find I tend to agree with Joel on specs... at least here. Who'd'a thunk...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by taking some code from the dev repo (file hgext/convert/filemap.py).  Works lots better. :D

Comment: @Maciek: Maybe I was too obscure: I took code from the development version of Mercurial.  At that time.  So, my "works better" refers to newer versions of hg.  Sadly, and you're right there, I can't recall exactly what difference there was.  I *think* the diff is that it now works as I expected it to in my OP.

Answer (score 1):

Hrm, I'll admit to not being able to figure out why what you have isn't working, but I can confirm it's not.

However, with my test src repo like this:

```
src
|-- bot
|   |-- aobiosbot.py
|   `-- excludeme
`-- dir1
    `-- includeme
```

and a filemap like this:

```
include dir1
include bot/aobiosbot.py
```

I end up with this:

```
dest
|-- bot
|   `-- aobiosbot.py
`-- dir1
    `-- includeme
```

You could bulld that filemap quickly by doing this in the repo root:

```
for thefile in * .* ; do
     echo include $thefile >> ../filemap
done
```

I'm **sure** there's a better way using exclude, but without reading the code for convert I can't find it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint for working around this.  And for kicking me to read the sources. Interesting, very interesting code.  Good thing it's not an important problem. :-)